# BackHandler - removeEventListener not called

Tags: react-native

I've added a special BackHandler event listener to a component screen, but because the listener doesn't get removed, that listener is called every time the BackPress happens even if I'm not at that "special component" anymore.

Here's my "special component" code handling BackHandler:

```
_backHandler() {
    this.goBack();//some function that is performed
    return true;
}

componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._backHandler.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
}
```

Can someone tell me how do I only allow this BackHandler event listener to used when I'm on that component itself OR how do I make sure it gets removed, when it gets unmount. Thanks!

P.S. lemme know if you need more information

Comment: I have tried that already, didn't work. Hence posted this.

Comment: You need to add the handler to `removeEventListener`. For this you need to bind your handler function on constructor and use it as `this._backHandler` in both or you can skip bindin with using arrow functions like the answer shows on that question.

Comment: binding function on constructor gave me function not defined error. But using arrow functions fixed it for me. Thanks!